# Вывод в listview данных записаны в строчку

Tags: java, android

Есть файл заполненный вот так `23 45 34` в строчку
как сделать так, чтобы в `listview` в столбик выводилось, а не в строку.
он берет из файла в котором так написано 
Вот так он выглядит

`6 7 8 16 17 18
20 28 42 48 46
22 30 44 50 48`

код

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
        List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stm);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                arr.add(line);
                count++;
                if (count == 20){
                    break;
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: покажите код, где у вас выводится в строчку

Comment: у меня есть где из файла в котором в столбик написано выводит а мне надо сделать чтобы если в файле в строку а выводило в лист как надо в столбик

Comment: Так приложите этот код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Collections.addAll(strList, line.split(" "));
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strList;
}
```

UPD по комментариям:

```
public List<List<String>> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<List<String>> strings= new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strList;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            strList = new ArrayList<>();
            Collections.addAll(strList, line.split(" "));
            strings.add(strList);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: а как выводить данные если у меня больше одной строки 2 или 3 ?

Comment: @Safet Этот код будет работать пока в файле не закончатся строки. Может приложить пример файла?

Comment: было бы не плохо

Comment: @Safet я имел ввиду, можете ли вы приложить пример вашего файла?

Comment: стоп а если допустим мне надо вот так первую строку выводить в один массив вторую во второй а третью уже в третий как тогда будет выглядеть?

Comment: а да сейчас выложу

Comment: все я выложил выше

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужно каждую строку в отдельный массив?

Comment: да все правильно вы понимаете

Comment: @Safet дополнил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60283/discussion-between-safet-and--a-).